# Batch checking if a file exists or not

Tags: batch-file

I need a batch code that will tell me if test.txt is there or not it is in the same directory as the batch file. I would like to know what I should put in the space where it says the code. Can anyone help?

```
rem the code
echo yes

rem the code
echo no
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
IF EXIST yourfilename (
echo Yes 
) ELSE (
echo No
)
```

Note : ELSE command must be on the same line as the end of the IF command.

To explore more type IF /? in cmd.